# IBM DB2 unable to access database from PYTHON after reboot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, db2

I was working in DB2 from jupyter-notebook in this way
SO: Windows10 python 3.8 and the library ibm_db: version 3.0.1

```
dsn = "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};" + \
  "DATABASE=BLUDB;" + \
  "HOSTNAME=dashdb-xxxxxxxxxal.bluemix.net;" + \
  "PORT=50000;" + \
  "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;" + \
  "UID=xxxxxxx;" + \
  "PWD=p^xxxxxxx;"
hdbc  = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
```

but I decided to restart the connection and i can't connect anymore

this returns the next message

> ----> 1 hdbc  = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
>
> SQLCODE=-5005on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL5005C  The operation failed because the database manager failed to access either the database manager configuration file or the database configuration file.

What could i do?

Comment: If you are running on Microsoft Windows, follow the advice here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-error-sql5005c-operation-failed-because-database-manager-failed-access-either-database-manager-configuration-file-or-database-configuration-file-system-startup

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: This is usually an access control / group-membership issue. Is your Windows workstation part of a domain, or is it itself a Windows-server?  What changes did you (or others) make after you first got python connecting to Db2?  Your question is not about programming. It is about troubleshooting, and that means it is up to you to do the work or fully describe your environment. You can also use the Process Explorer (download from microsoft) to follow file system errors and thus resolve the issue.